# new Date() do chrome vindo no horário de verão (nov 2019)

Tags: javascript

Já faz 6 meses que o governo anunciou que não ia ter horário de verão, e mesmo assim a google não parece ter feito nada em relação a isso.
Comecei a ter um problema por causa que o new Date() está trazendo no horário de verão, enquanto no IE está correto.

Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Provavelmente atualizando o navegador (ou esperando um patch da empresa se não resolver).

Comment: Funcionou Bacco, obrigado. Não aparecia para atualizar, mas clicando "sobre" atualizou sozinho